# SQL com SELECT e SUBSELECT para montar um chat

Tags: mysql, sql

Olá galera do Stackoverflow, estou montando o SQL abaixo para montar um chat de atendimento ao usuário, que trás a lista de todas as conversas ativas, porém estou com um problema, meu SQL está trazendo a ultima mensagem de acordo com o id do Cliente, ou seja se a minha mensagem for a ultima, ele não exibe, e eu preciso colocar um COUNT se houverem mensagens novas caso a data_mensagem for > que a data_mensagem(atual) pra mim trazer as notificações de quantas mensagens são.

OBS: Tabela que armazena as mensagens: http://prntscr.com/jmkde8

```
SELECT CLI.id, CLI.nome, CLI.senha, CLI.email, CLI.cpf, CLI.celular, CLI.data_nasc, CLI.genero, CLI.data_cadastro, CLI.status, CLI.id_socket, ATEN.mensagem, COUNT(ATEN.mensagem) AS novas_mensagens, SUM(COMP.valor) AS valor_total, COMP.data AS ultima_compra, ARQ.nome AS foto, ATEN.data_mensagem
FROM ut_clientes AS CLI

LEFT JOIN ut_compras AS COMP ON COMP.id_cliente = CLI.id
LEFT JOIN ut_arquivos AS ARQ ON ARQ.id_tipo = CLI.id AND ARQ.tipo = 'ut_clientes'
LEFT JOIN ut_atendimentos AS ATEN ON ATEN.id_usuario_envio = CLI.id

WHERE ATEN.id_usuario_envio
  AND NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT ATEN.id_usuario_envio
    FROM ut_atendimentos AS ATEN2
    WHERE ATEN2.id_usuario_envio = CLI.id
    AND ATEN2.data_mensagem > ATEN.data_mensagem
  )
GROUP BY CLI.id
ORDER BY ATEN.data_mensagem DESC
```

Não sei se a ideia ficou clara, mas qualquer coisa é só me perguntar, agradeceria se alguém pudesse dar uma luz kkk

Valeu!

Comment: Não ficou claro. Tem como colocar os conteúdos tabelas e exemplos do que você espera?

Comment: Não está faltando nada nessa parte?  `WHERE ATEN.id_usuario_envio
  AND NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Claro, acho que com o front-end vai ficar mais simples, assim é como está sendo retornado agora: http://prntscr.com/jmkkpq, pode ver que a minha mensagem não é a ultima na lista exibida no chatlist do cliente, a ideia do COUNT, é, ao não estar ativo com o cliente um COUNT com o numero de mensagens não lidas será exibido (estilo WhatsApp)